# Exception when calling MenuItem.getActionProvider()

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

So I have this override method on one of my activities (AppCompatActivity) and it is from an old project of mine that was developed on Eclipse Luna.

I am getting Exception whenever I call:

```
_shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
```

The Exception info:

```
2018-10-25 15:39:22.332 20677-20677/com.eibimalul.smartgallery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.eibimalul.smartgallery, PID: 20677
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionProvider(MenuItemImpl.java:782)
        at com.eibimalul.smartgallery.SingleImageDisplayActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SingleImageDisplayActivity.java:309)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3465)
```

Here is my method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

        _shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

        Intent shareIntent = createShareIntent();
        _shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

        return true;
    }
```

**Edit:**

Just to clarify:

Somewhere else in my code I need to use:

```
_sharedActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

So if I want to use what @sasikumar suggested bellow, it means I need to change the provider type and the new type does not have the setShareIntent method.

Answer (score 2):

So I have managed to find the problem and solve it, with the help of sasikumar's comment:

So I did have to use:

```
MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem)
```

but, I had to change the type of my ActionProvider to:

```
android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
```

And now, I could safely cast the result from the getActionProvider, and maintain the ability to set the share intent using:

```
_shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent)
```

In addition to that, I had to change the namespace of the ShareActionProvider as well

from:

```
android.widget.ShareActionProvider
```

to:

```
android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem)
```

instead of

```
item.getActionProvider();
```

Comment: Thanks @sasikumar. But after I do that I get a compilation error saying: "incopatible types; cannot cast android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider to android.widget.ShareActionProvider". When I change the type of my member to the former, I loose the ability somewhere else on that provider to call: setShareIntent().